# Javascript XSS Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I have a javascript / jquery code for searching and i tested inserting a script tag with an alert and i found out that my search was vulnerable to an XSS. May i ask if is there a way to filter the search?

Here is my code.

```
$('#search').keyup(function(e){
    if($.trim($(this).val()) != ''){
        $.get("php/api.php",{"function":"Searching","search": $(this).val() },function(e){
            $('#search-result').html(e);
        });
        $('#search-result').show();
        if(e.which == 13) {
            location.href = 'search.php?result='+$(this).val();
        }
    }else{
        $('#search-result').html("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the script tag from user input you can use the below function

```
 function stripScripts(s) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = s;
    var scripts = div.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var i = scripts.length;
    while (i--) {
      scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
    }
    return div.innerHTML;
  }

 stripScripts('<span><script type="text/javascript">alert(\'foo\');<\/script><\/span>')
```

But thats going to prevent only a specfic type of XSS. Check this [link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) for more details.